# How to test if collection contains all elements of other collection

Tags: ceylon

With a `Set` in Ceylon it is straightforward to determine if one collection is a superset of the other. It's just `first.superset(second)`. What's the best way to do the equivalent for an `Iterable`, `List`, or `Sequential` using [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) (or bag) semantics? For example something like the pseudocode below:

```
{'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'}.containsAll({'b', 'a'}) // Should be true
{'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'}.containsAll({'a', 'a'}) // Should be false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [`Category.containsEvery`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/Category.type.html#containsEvery), which is inherited by Iterable. It checks for each element of the parameter whether it is contained in the receiver, so that `bigger.containsEvery(smaller)` is equivalent to this:

```ceylon
smaller.every(bigger.contains)
```

(Note that it is swapped around.) The expression in the brackets here is a method reference, we could also write this expanded with a lambda:

```ceylon
smaller.every(o => bigger.contains(o))
```

So in your example:

```ceylon
print({'a', 'b', 'b'}.containsEvery({'b', 'a'})); // Should be true
print({'a', 'b', 'b'}.containsEvery({'a', 'a'})); // Should be false
```

... actually, those both return true. Why do you think the latter one is false?

Did you think of multiset semantics (i.e. the number of occurrences in the "superset" iterable need to be at least as much as the smaller one)? Or do you want a sublist? Or do you just want to know whether the second iterable is at the start of the first (startswith)?

I don't know about any **multiset** implementation for Ceylon (I found a [multimap](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/com/vasileff/ceylon/structures/0.0.0/module-doc/api/Multimap.type.html), though). If you are running on the JVM, you can use any Java one, like from Guava (though that also doesn't have a "contains all with multiples" function, as far as I can see).
For small iterables, you can use [`.frequencies()`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/Iterable.type.html#frequencies) and then compare the numbers:

```ceylon
Boolean isSuperMultiset<Element>({Element*} bigger,
                                 {Element*} smaller) =>
     let (bigFreq = bigger.frequencies())
        every({ for(key->count in smaller.frequencies())
                count <= (bigFreq[key] else 0) })
```

**For sublist semantics**, the SearchableList interface has the [`includes`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/SearchableList.type.html#includes) method, which checks whether another list is a sublist. (It is not implemented by many classes, though, you would need to convert your first iterable into an Array, assuming it is not a String/StringBuilder.)

**For startsWith semantics**, you could convert both to lists and use then [`List.startsWith`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/List.type.html#startsWith). There should be a more efficient way of doing that (you just could go through both iterators in parallel).

There is [`corresponding`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/index.html#corresponding), but it just stops after the shorter one ends (i.e. it answers the question "does any of those two iterables start with the other", without telling which one is the longer one). Same for a bunch of other pair related functions in ceylon.language.

If you know the length of both of the Iterables (or are confident that `.size` is fast), that should solve the issue:

```ceylon
Boolean startsWith<Element>({Element*}longer, {Element*}shorter) =>
     shorter.size <= longer.size &&
     corresponding(longer, shorter);
```

Comment: "Did you think of multiset semantics..." Yes, this is what I was going for. I updated the examples to be clearer.

Comment: `frequencies()` discards nulls. If that's not what you want, you should map each element in both streams to a `Singleton` sequence before calling `frequencies()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two `Sequential`s, then you can remove each right-hand character one at a time from the left-hand sequence until you either remove them all or fail to remove one of them.

```
Boolean containsAll<Element>([Element*] collection, [Element*] other)
        given Element satisfies Object {
    variable value remaining = collection;

    for (element1 in other) {
        value position = remaining.locate((element2) => element1 == element2);
        if (exists position) {
            remaining = remaining.initial(position.key).append(remaining.spanFrom(position.key + 1));
        } else {
            // Element was not found in remaining; terminate early
            return false;
        }
    }

    // All elements were found
    return true;
}

print(containsAll(['a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b']));
print(containsAll(['a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'a']));
```

Append only exists on `Sequential` so it won't work on just a `List` or an `Iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

The `containsEvery` function should do what you want ([try it!](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=14fee97af0cf1127f6a68b631a0e035b)). Alternatively, you can also turn both streams into sets using the `set` function ([try it!](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=847ffbe11c00e50a6fec69c7102c8106)), or use `every` and `contains` ([try it!](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=4fcd47cea1ab1e5be7c2ab78758fadb1)).

Comment: My examples were not good. Hopefully, the new ones are clearer. I want to test if the stream on the left has all of the elements of the stream on the right, including at least as many of each element.